# Error: 404008: Resource Not Found While Exporting View into CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, populate, tableau-api

I'm trying to export data from a dashboard to csv. I found the populate_csv(view_item) function but have a trouble running the script.

This is the error that i receive: 
**404008: Resource Not Found
        API version '2.7' does not support access to the given resource.**

Does anyone know another way to export data into CSV using python. Below is my starter code. Thanks a lot!

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC

tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('user', '###########')

server = TSC.Server('xxxxxxxxxx')



# change current api version from 2.3 to 2.7

server.version = '2.7'



with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth): 

    wconnect = server.workbooks.get_by_id('2ff8366c-8398-4dc0-b810-e648f90208a7') 

    vfound = wconnect.views

    view_item = vfound[0] 

    print(vars(vfound[0])) 

    server.views.populate_csv(view_item) 

    with open('view_csv2.csv','wb') as f:

        f.write(b''.join(view_item.csv))
```

Does anyone know why and what i need to do to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with version 2.7 but it worked fine with 2.8